# javascript - read a seperate tab to check if it's open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to somehow read / check if another browser tab is open before opening the requested tab.

For example:

This is for my traffic exchange site, they just open mysite.com/surf.php and leave it viewing user's submitted sites in a frame.  They earn points just for leaving that running.

Now lets say USER A has SURF PAGE A running fine and then opens SURF PAGE B then he has 2 mysite.com/surf.php running and earning double the points everybody else will earn.

What I want to happen is:

USER A has SURF PAGE A running fine and then tries to open SURF PAGE B which will check if another mysite.com/surf.php is already open and if it is to redirect the request for the 2nd surf page to another mysite.com/surf-error.php

So they can only ever have 1 mysite.com/surf.php running at any given time.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: It'd be easier to simply say "one user can maximum gain `x` points a second" and if the last time they gained a point was less than `y`, then don't add a point.

Comment: set a session variable. If you're already tracking time don't track time a second time.

Comment: Track it using a database as storage.

Comment: I can't limit a users x points as different sites earn a different amount of coins.  Also how would I set a session variable or track it using database as storage?

Comment: There's nothing to stop someone from opening surf.php in different browsers though

Comment: Yes so the maximum possible they could do is open 1 surf.php in each browser but that's not a real issue.  The main issue is that users have figured out they can have 50 tabs running and be earning insane amount of coins.  If I can limit it down to 1 per browser everything would be perfect

Comment: Wait, why can't I open 50 browsers instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser windows on the same domain in the same browser can exchange some information via:

1. Cookies
2. Local Storage
3. Communication with a common server

You can use 1) or 2) to store some information about an active page and refuse to let other pages be active if one is already active.

But, the most reliable way to enforce policies like you are asking about is to use the actual server to enforce it.  If users have a login, then code the server to only allow a logged in user to accumulate points for one site at a time.

Other than these options, if you want to enforce it all client-side, you would probably need a browser-plugin that could monitor all open browser windows (which I assume is not practical).  You cannot do monitoring of multiple windows opened by the user from plain javascript in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

when you start tracking time for someone set a session variable

```
session.trackingtime = true
```

when you check again to start tracking time make sure that value is set to `false`. When you stop tracking time set the variables to `false`.

Comment: Hello, I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Would you be able to show me examples or how I could incorporate this in to my site?

Comment: how do you track users are gaining coins? Check to make sure they aren't already gaining coins before you start counting again.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something very similar today. Just update the `else if` part to do a redirect in your case.

```
// helper function to set cookies
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, seconds) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (seconds * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

// helper function to get a cookie
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

// Do not allow multiple call center tabs
if (~window.location.hash.indexOf('#admin/callcenter')) {
    $(window).on('beforeunload onbeforeunload', function(){
        document.cookie = 'ic_window_id=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;';
    });

    function validateCallCenterTab() {
        var win_id_cookie_duration = 10; // in seconds

        if (!window.name) {
            window.name = Math.random().toString();
        }

        if (!getCookie('ic_window_id') || window.name === getCookie('ic_window_id')) {
            // This means they are using just one tab. Set/clobber the cookie to prolong the tab's validity.
            setCookie('ic_window_id', window.name, win_id_cookie_duration);
        } else if (getCookie('ic_window_id') !== window.name) {
            // this means another browser tab is open, alert them to close the tabs until there is only one remaining
            var message = 'You cannot have this website open in multiple tabs. ' +
                'Please close them until there is only one remaining. Thanks!';
            $('html').html(message);
            clearInterval(callCenterInterval);
            throw 'Multiple call center tabs error. Program terminating.';
        }
    }

    callCenterInterval = setInterval(validateCallCenterTab, 3000);
}
```